# How to configure SVN access control

Tags: apache, svn, apache2, webdav

I want to restrict access of selected users to selected SVN repositories by Apache. However, as I did the configuration using the authz mechanism, I don't have any access to the repositories after logging into SVN. `http://<my_server>/svn/` displays a *"Collection of Repositories"* list which is empty. `http://<my_server>/svn/mytestrepo1` is showing *"Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource."*

The configuration looks like this (Debian OS):

1. the repositories are located in `/svn` directory
2. I created the users with the command `htpasswd -cm /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd admin1`
3. content of the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf` file:

```
<Location /svn>

DAV svn
SVNParentPath /svn
SVNListParentPath On
AuthType Basic
AuthName "SVN repos"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn_access.acl
# <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
Require valid-user
# </LimitExcept>

</Location>
```

4. content of the /etc/apache2/svn_access.acl file:

```
[groups]
admin = admin1
users = test1

[/]
* = r
@admin = rw

[repo:/mytestrepo1]
@users = rw
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it. My `svn_access.acl` file had a lot of tabbed and commented lines. When I cleaned it and started with simple:

```
[/]
* = rw
```

it is working.